# Access a value in a dictionary using an int variable in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, tuples, nsdictionary

I'm developing an iOS app and I want to access a specific value in a Dictionary using `Array()`.

My dictionary contains an array, which contains structs.

```
let array = [(key: "S", value: [Thunderbolt.repoStruct(repoName: "Semiak Repo", repoURL: "https://repo.semiak.dev", icon: Optional("iconRound"))]), (key: "T", value: [Thunderbolt.repoStruct(repoName: "Thunderbolt iOS Utilities", repoURL: "https://repo.thunderbolt.semiak.dev", icon: Optional("iconRound"))])]
```

I'm making an `UITableView` with the array: the section name is the `key` value, the cell title is the `repoStruct.repoName` value, and the same with the following values.

To access repoName I'd use `Array(array)[0].1[0].repoName`.

The problem is that I do not know the exact location I want to access, instead, I use indexPath to know which value I need:

```
Array(array)[indexPath.section].indexPath.row[0].repoName
```

This should return me the repoName of the cell, but instead gives me the following error: `Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: [repoStruct])' has no member 'indexPath'`

I also tried using:

```
let row = indexPath.row
Array(array)[indexPath.section].row[0].repoName
```

but it gives me the same error: `Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: [repoStruct])' has no member 'row'`

I do not know why `Array(array)[0].1` works and returns me the value, but `Array(array)[indexPath.section].row` doesn't. It is doing the same: accessing a value using the position, which is an int, such as indexPath.

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are strongly discouraged from using tuples in a data source array. Replace the tuple with an extra struct

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    let items : [Thunderbolt.repoStruct]
}

let array = [Section(name: "S", items: [Thunderbolt.repoStruct(repoName: "Semiak Repo", repoURL: "https://repo.semiak.dev", icon: Optional("iconRound"))], 
             Section(name: "T", items: [Thunderbolt.repoStruct(repoName: "Thunderbolt iOS Utilities", repoURL: "https://repo.thunderbolt.semiak.dev", icon: Optional("iconRound"))]]
```

and get an item at index path

```
let section = array[indexPath.section]
let item = section.items[indexPath.row]
let name = item.repoName
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `array` is already an array, so there's no need to say `Array(array)` - simply `array` will suffice, although generic names like this should be avoided.

> I do not know why `array[0].1[0]` works

Let's pick this apart - your're accessing the first element in `array` via `[0]` and within that, the second element of the tuple `.1`, and lastly the first element of that `value`array. You could use `array[0].value[0]` for the same effect and make the code more readable.

> but `array[indexPath.section].row` doesn't

That's because your array does not contain anything called `row`.

Use `array[indexPath.section].value[indexPath.row].repoName` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
let dictData = arr[indexpath.section] //Element of section
let value = dictData["value"] //Value added in value in The element
let name = value[indexpath.row].reponame //Gives you name
```